# Is it allowed for a poset to have an element that is not related to any other elements?

Tags: order-theory

For example, is the poset $\{(a,b),c\}$ allowed?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the matter?  How would this break (or fail to break) the definition of a poset?

Comment: I thought it would be odd to draw a hasse diagram with an element not connected to the rest of the elements...

Comment: The answer to the question in title is yes. I don't understand your notation. How is the two element set $\{(a,b),c\}$ a poset??

Comment: It is the notation used in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearExtension.html, i believe it means the posets have elements a b and c but $a \geq b$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your set is not a poset.  A poset has two parts, the set S and the (partial) order <=, written (S,<=).  An antichain is a poset for which no element is related to any other element.  The set S = {a,b,c} with the order { (a,a), (b,b), (c,c) } is an antichain.  Exercise.  Show that antichains can be as large as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i guess i got confused about the notation. So what I intended to ask is if S={a,b,c} with the ordering {(a,b)} is a poset.

Comment: @User00001.  Only if you state you are using strict orders.